# Evaluate polymorphic objects at compile time

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

### Problem

I'm trying to create a "Precision" type for a strongly typed interface. However, I cant seem to make it evaluate at compile time. Is there something I am missing ?

### Code

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint8_t DOUBLE_MAX_PRECISION{ 16 };
constexpr uint8_t FLOAT_MAX_PRECISION {  7 };

template<uint8_t max>
struct BoundType
{
    constexpr BoundType(uint8_t value) : value{ value }
    {
       if(value > max) {
           value = max;
       }
    }

    const uint8_t value;
};

template <typename T> struct Precision {};

template<> 
struct Precision<double> : public BoundType<DOUBLE_MAX_PRECISION>
{
   constexpr Precision(uint8_t value) : BoundType(value) {}
};

template<>
struct Precision<float> : public BoundType<FLOAT_MAX_PRECISION>
{
    constexpr Precision(uint8_t value) : BoundType(value) {}
};
```

### Use case

```
void print(double number, const Precision<double>&& precision)
{
    uint8_t prec = precision.value;

    //use prec here to print the numbers decimal digits
}

void print(float number, const Precision<float>&& precision)
{
    uint8_t prec = precision.value;

    //use prec here to print the numbers decimal digits
}

int main()
{
    print(10.0, Precision<double>(10));
    print(10.0, Precision<float>(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/FRRBtW

### Edit

After reading your suggestions I came up with a solution that does evaluate at compile time ! I used godbolt under x86-64 gcc (trunk) with the -Os flag and some minor code changes.

I'm sharing the code not only to help out those in need but also for people to modify and suggest better solutions in this thread.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/Q8Q3L4

Comment: You probably want `constexpr BoundType(uint8_t value) : value{ std::min(max, value) } {}`, as changing input parameter in body is useless, and member is const anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your value in a `constexpr` context, although in general it still won't guarantee compile-time evaluation (for that c++20 added `consteval`), but in practice it's usually enough to assign the value that you want to be compile-time computed to a `constexpr` variable, i.e.:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto foo = Precision<double>(10);
    print(10.0, foo); // change the signature to const ref
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you are compiling with no optimizations which may also contribute to the compiler's unwillingness to do more than necessary.